# How to import a list in HTML into R?

Tags: html, r, import

I would like import a list of the banks in Cambodia with homepage, address and so on into R as you can see below:

[image: List of the banks]

I try to use the code below but it can't import to R:

```
url <- "https://www.abc.org.kh/member-list/"
html <- read_html(url)

links <- html %>% 
  html_nodes("a") %>%
  html_attr("href")

text <- html %>% 
  html_nodes("p") %>%
  html_text()

class <- html %>% 
  html_nodes("div") %>%
  html_attr("class")

table <- html %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  html_table()

table_df <- as.data.frame(table)
```

Please guide me how to do!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The code posted in the question is extracting `text` where all wand information is, the pipes after that one are not needed.
Here is a way.  define functions to extract address, telephone, e-mail andd website from `text` and call those functions in a `extract_info` function that takes care of it.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(rvest)
})

address <- function(x) sapply(x, `[[`, 1)
phone <- function(x) sapply(x, `[[`, 2)
mail <- function(x) {
  n <- lengths(x)
  y <- character(length(x))
  y[n == 4] <- sapply(x[n == 4], `[[`, 3)
  temp <- sapply(x[n == 3], `[[`, 3)
  i <- sapply(temp, \(tt) grepl("@", tt))
  temp[!i] <- ""
  y[n == 3] <- temp
  is.na(y) <- (nchar(y) == 0) | (y == "N/A")
  y
}
website <- function(x) {
  n <- lengths(x)
  y <- character(length(x))
  y[n == 4] <- sapply(x[n == 4], `[[`, 4)
  temp <- sapply(x[n == 3], `[[`, 3)
  i <- sapply(temp, \(tt) grepl("@", tt))
  temp[i] <- ""
  y[n == 3] <- temp
  is.na(y) <- (nchar(y) == 0) | (y == "N/A")
  y
}

extract_info <- function(x) {
  i <- grep("Address:", x, ignore.case = TRUE)
  x <- x[i]
  y <- gsub("Address:|Tel:|Phone:|Mail:|Email:|Website:", "<<dummy>>", x)
  y <- strsplit(y, "<<dummy>>")
  y <- lapply(y, `[`, -1)
  y <- lapply(y, trimws)
  Address <- address(y)
  Tel <- phone(y)
  Mail <- mail(y)
  Website <- website(y)
  data.frame(Address, Tel, Mail, Website)
}

url <- "https://www.abc.org.kh/member-list/"
html <- read_html(url)

text <- html %>% 
  html_elements("p") %>%
  html_text()

out <- extract_info(text)
head(out)
#>                                                                                                                                                                                                      Address
#> 1                                                                                                                         61, Preah Monivong Blvd., Sangkat Srah Chork, Khan Daun Penh, Phnom Penh, Cambodia
#> 2                               Building No. 141, 146, 148 and 148 ABCD, Pheah Sihanouk Blvd., and No. 15 and 153 ABC, Street 278, Phum 4, Sangkat Boeng Keng Kang Ti Mouy, Khan Boeng Keng Kang, Phnom Penh
#> 3                                                                                                                                        #13, St. 7, Sangkat Chaktomuk, Khan Duan Penh, Phnom Penh, Cambodia
#> 4 The Gateway Building, Floor 33rd, Russian Federation (St. 110) Sangkat Phsar Depou Ti 3, Khan Toul Kork, Phnom Penh, Cambodia (Current address: No 183B, Street 132, Khan Toul Kork, Phnom Penh, Cambodia)
#> 5                                                                                               No. 132, Corner of Street 294 and Norodom Blvd. Sangkat Tonle Bassac, Khan Chamkarmon, Phnom Penh, Cambodia.
#> 6                                                                                                              No.462, Preah Monivong Blvd (93), Sangkat Tonle Bassac, Khan Chamkarmon, Phnom Penh, Cambodia
#>                       Tel                         Mail                   Website
#> 1     023 998 777/430 999 acledabank@acledabank.com.kh     www.acledabank.com.kh
#> 2             098 203 513             info@ababank.com           www.ababank.com
#> 3     023 220 810/220 811            admin@ardb.com.kh  https://www.ardb.com.kh/
#> 4             023 886 688               info@acbnk.com             www.acbnk.com
#> 5             023 211 888          info@apdbank.com.kh http://www.apdbank.com.kh
#> 6 023 901 338/023 901 348          info@bicbank.com.kh        www.bicbank.com.kh
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>